# Получение относительного пути к .pro файлу приложения

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, как программно получить относительный путь к pro файлу приложения, по аналогии с переменной PWD qmake? Пробовал использовать класс QDir, но как я понял у него нет таких функций.

Comment: Где получить-то? В с++ приложении этот путь никак не фигурирует. Если только самому пробрасывать.

Comment: зачем?  pro-файл — это часть системы сборки и не должен распространяться вместе с приложением... скорей всего тут [ошибка XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy/710#710).

Comment: возможно имеется ввиду `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath`.  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath ?